# tooling api not working for create class

Tags: tooling-api, unauthorized-endpoint

I have created Apex Class that use tooling api and have one method that generate One class dynamically

```
public with sharing class SalesforceTool
{
    final String endpoint = 'https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/tooling/sobjects';

    // SomeValues to be store
    public String oid ;
    public String cid ;
    public String apmid ;
    public String carid ;

    public SalesforceTool()
    {
    }

    // used receive response by sending a http request
    private String getResponse(HttpRequest req)
    {
        try
        {
            Http
            httpreq = new Http();
            HttpResponse
            res = httpreq.send(req);
            String reqresponse = res.getBody();
            return
            reqresponse;
        }
        catch (Exception e){return
        'Error:' +e.getMessage();}
    }

    // create a http request with required endpoint and request method
    private HttpRequest createHttpRequest(String endpoint, String method)
    {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        endpoint += '';
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod(method);
        return req;
    }

    public void createApexClass()
{
    // create a Http request with post method
    HttpRequest req = createHttpRequest(endpoint+'/ApexClass','POST');
    req.setBody( '{"Name":"NewApexClass1","Body":"public class NewApexClass1 {}"}');

    String response = getResponse(req);

}
}
```

When I called this method from developer console .

```
SalesforceTool sf = new SalesforceTool();
sf.createApexClass();
```

New class is not created

when I try to run end point url

https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/tooling

it says error

```
Errors>
<Error>
<errorCode>INVALID_SESSION_ID</errorCode>
<message>Session expired or invalid</message>
</Error>
</Errors>
```

I also try to run command

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 00D90000000lZg3!ASAAQORxuDb4zTM4yHCL6C5KrgI8Za.r4Hpzkya.Ztl7odMxm_wJqnPaW82_Jp28hDyPrQxxGWx.EdHGDjX5DYaJP7pW6td_" "https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/tooling/sobjects"
```

it is giving output

```
{"runTestsAsynchronous":"/services/data/v28.0/tooling/runTestsAsynchronous","search":"/services/data/v28.0/tooling/search","composite":"/services/data/v28.0/tooling/composite","query":"/services/data/v28.0/tooling/query","completions":"/services/data/v28.0/tooling/completions","sobjects":"/services/data/v28.0/tooling/sobjects","executeAnonymous":"/services/data/v28.0/tooling/executeAnonymous","runTestsSynchronous":"/services/data/v28.0/tooling/runTestsSynchronous"}
```

But New class is not creating
. it this problem in end point url or I am skipping steps to be done ?

Comment: Can you print the `response ` variable in system.debug to see what are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of this code [here](https://ashwanisoni.wordpress.com/). I am not sure from where you got this.

> Please make sure you have added 'https://ap1.salesforce.com' in Remote
>   Site settings.

Try following code snippet. I corrected indentation and added a `system.debug` only and it worked.

```
public with sharing class SalesforceTool
{
    final String endpoint = 'https://huddle-idp-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/tooling/sobjects';

    // SomeValues to be store
    public String oid ;
    public String cid ;
    public String apmid ;
    public String carid ;

    public SalesforceTool()
    {
    }

    // used receive response by sending a http request
    private String getResponse(HttpRequest req)
    {
        try
        {
            Http httpreq = new Http();
            HttpResponse res = httpreq.send(req);
            String reqresponse = res.getBody();
            return reqresponse;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.debug(' ==> Error: '+e.getMessage());
            return 'Error:' +e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    // create a http request with required endpoint and request method
    private HttpRequest createHttpRequest(String endpoint, String method)
    {
        HttpRequest req = new
        HttpRequest();
        endpoint += '';
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod(method);
        return req;
    }

    public void createApexClass()
    {
        // create a Http request with post method
        HttpRequest req = createHttpRequest(endpoint+'/ApexClass','POST');
        req.setBody( '{"Name":"NewApexClass1","Body":"public class NewApexClass1 {}"}');
        // send request and receive response
        String response = getResponse(req);
        System.debug(' ==> '+response);
        // These two lines have no role in creating apex class. So they can be ignored for now.
        //Map<String,Object> rmp = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeuntyped(response);
        //oid = (String)rmp.get('id');
    }
}
```

**Execute Anonymous:**

```
SalesforceTool sf = new SalesforceTool();
sf.createApexClass();
```

Response:
[image]